# Scrapy Python Web Scraping JSON

Tags: python, json, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am struggling trying to figure out how to scrape JSON response using Scrapy Python. I was able to successfully scrape JSON on a different page on the same site. I would appreciate any help.

How would I scrape values in "tournamentGroup" (i.e. id, name) as well as year, title, etc.

Partial Code:

```
start_url = 'https://api.wtatennis.com/tennis/tournaments/?page=0&pageSize=100&excludeLevels=ITF&from=2020-09-01&to=2020-09-30'
    
with urllib.request.urlopen(start_url) as start_url:
    json_obj = start_url.read()
    rank_list = json.loads(json_obj)

    for item in rank_list:
        
        rank_data = []
        tourney_id = item['content']['id']
        tourney_year = item['year']
    
        rank_data = [tourney_id, tourney_year]
 
        cur.execute("""insert into wta_rankings(tourney_id, tourney_year) 
                    values(%s, %s)
                    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"""
                    ,(rank_data))
        conn.commit()        
    cur.close()

JSON:
{
   "pageInfo":{
      "page":0,
      "numPages":0,
      "pageSize":100,
      "numEntries":10
   },
   "content":[
      {
         "tournamentGroup":{
            "id":2023,
            "name":"Prague 125K",
            "level":"125K",
            "metadata":null
         },
         "year":2020,
         "title":"Prague Open",
         "startDate":"2020-08-29",
         "endDate":"2020-09-06",
         "surface":"Clay",
         "inOutdoor":"O",
         "city":"PRAGUE",
         "country":"Czech Republic",
         "singlesDrawSize":128,
         "doublesDrawSize":32,
         "prizeMoney":3125000,
         "prizeMoneyCurrency":"USD",
         "liveScoringId":"2023"
      },
```

URL Example: https://api.wtatennis.com/tennis/tournaments/?page=0&pageSize=100&excludeLevels=ITF&from=2020-09-01&to=2020-09-30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.wtatennis.com/tennis/tournaments/?page=0&pageSize=100&excludeLevels=ITF&from=2020-09-01&to=2020-09-30"

response = requests.get(url).json()

for item in response["content"]:
    print(f"{item['tournamentGroup']['name']} - {item['year']} - {item['title']}")
```

This gives you (it's just a sample, you can get any field you want):

```
Prague 125K - 2020 - Prague Open
US OPEN - 2020 - US Open - New York, United States, NY
WARSAW - 2020 - BNP Paribas Warsaw Open - Warsaw, Poland
ISTANBUL - 2020 - TEB BNP Paribas Tennis Championship Istanbul - Istanbul, Turkey
MADRID - 2020 - Mutua Madrid Open - Madrid, Spain
HIROSHIMA - 2020 - Hana-cupid Japan Women's Open - Hiroshima, Japan
ROME - 2020 - Internazionali BNL d'Italia - Rome, Italy
STRASBOURG - 2020 - Internationaux de Strasbourg - Strasbourg, France
ROLAND GARROS - 2020 - Roland Garros - Paris, France
TASHKENT - 2020 - Tashkent Open - Tashkent, Uzbekistan
```

If you struggle with "navigating" through the JSON, just copy the response contents into an online [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/), click the `wrench` icon to fix it and then `Format / Beautify`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answered my question and made my day!

Comment: I'm glad it did. If you find the answer useful, please accept it.